# I can make a strange clicking sound with my soft palate. What is this?

Tags: phonetics, articulation

Not sure if here is exactly the right place to be asking this question, but whatever this is probably overlaps with linguistics/phonetics in some way. 
The best way I can describe it in words is like the way you would roll an “R” in the same place in your mouth but with a different tongue position. It sounds similar to the clicking some marine mammals can produce. 
Here are some audio recordings of me making the sound. The microphone was quite close to my mouth - it is not as loud in real life as you hear it here. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wf3dphaqadjlhf3/Audio%202023-04-07%2022.53.24.m4a?dl=0 
 https://www.dropbox.com/s/amd6wn15m4ghzc0/Audio%202023-04-08%2001.46.00.m4a?dl=0

Comment: A few clear recordings are, at the minimum, required so that we can guess what you are talking about. But it's not part of language, I guess

Comment: I can make that sound too ─ and I have always wondered. Some type of palatal click?

Comment: Until you hear the sound in question, I don't know how you would decide if it's the same or different. Even if it is a click, what's your basis of comparison for saying it's palatal and not e.g. dental?

Comment: @user6726 I have added a recording, and in response to your question about my basis of comparison - I don’t have one, but I think the sound’s palatal because that’s where I can feel it being made.

Comment: oh wait were you talking to @nearsighted or me when you wrote that second comment?

Comment: I believe that’s the sound of a moped driving past a block over.

Comment: That's a different sound than I expected; nope, can't make that, and it's mystifying. It almost sounds like an ejective?

Comment: The book to read is J.C. Catford's _A Practical Introduction to Phonetics_, which is designed for autodidacts studying speech (a singularly difficult task) and full of little experiments one can practice to produce and identify sounds with all sorts of phonetic features. There's nothing like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on listening to the recording, it is not a click, which has two places of articulation (lingual or labial plus back), complete closures and involves rarifaction (by tonque or jaw lowering) and release (ingressive air). It is not a linguistic sound at all. It involves a narrowing of the passage between the tongue body and the soft palate, which creates a kind of "trilling". The closest linguistic sound is a "uvular trill": you can here expert IPA productions [here](https://www.internationalphoneticassociation.org/IPAcharts/inter_chart_2018/IPA_2018.html) (look for "R"). It sounds like a geiger counter which people say "clicks", so it is not unreasonable to call it a clicking sound, but it's not a click in the linguistic sense.